# How do I call the ReplaceFile function from C#?

Tags: c#, winapi

I have googled a lot about this and couldn't find any solution, so posting here.
From Microsoft [document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/windows/desktop/aa365512(v=vs.85).aspx)

```
BOOL WINAPI ReplaceFile(
      _In_       LPCTSTR lpReplacedFileName,
      _In_       LPCTSTR lpReplacementFileName,
      _In_opt_   LPCTSTR lpBackupFileName,
      _In_       DWORD   dwReplaceFlags,
      _Reserved_ LPVOID  lpExclude,
      _Reserved_ LPVOID  lpReserved
    );
```

I need to implement this in c# I now the basic structure.

```
[DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool ReplaceFile(
       ///argument implemetation here
    );
```

But i don't know how to implement the arguments in c#. I googled a lot but didnt get a solution.
Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According the [pinvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net) info on [ReplaceFile](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/ReplaceFile.html), this is what you need:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError=true, CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
static extern bool ReplaceFile(
   string           lpReplacedFileName,
   string           lpReplacementFileName, 
   string           lpBackupFileName, 
   ReplaceFileFlags dwReplaceFlags, 
   IntPtr           lpExclude, 
   IntPtr           lpReserved);

[Flags]
enum ReplaceFileFlags : uint
{
    REPLACEFILE_WRITE_THROUGH       = 0x00000001,
    REPLACEFILE_IGNORE_MERGE_ERRORS = 0x00000002,
    REPLACEFILE_IGNORE_ACL_ERRORS   = 0x00000004,
}
```

Just pass `IntPtr.Zero` for the last two parameters. According to the [SDK documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/windows/desktop/aa365512.aspx), they are not used. The same documentation will explain the purpose of the other parameters.